# Call to a member function roles() on null in laravel when I redirect to a create page

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Please help me with this `Call to a member function roles() on null` error in laravel. In every page It works but when i call a create method it throw this error. i am giving the code below.

`web.php`

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware('can:access-all')->group(function (){
    Route::resource('/library','LibraryController', ['except' => ['show']]);
});
```

in `User.php`

```
public function hasAnyRoles($roles)
{
    if ($this->roles()->whereIn('name', $roles)->first()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

in `role.php`

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

in `LibraryController`

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
public function create()
{
    return redirect('books.create');
}
```

in `layouts\app.blade.php`

```
<span>{{ implode(', ',Auth::user()->roles()->get()->pluck('name')->toArray()) }}</span>
```

from every page I have done in my project everywhere it works correctly but here it's not working. Any solution to handle this error on every page before I made and after I working for?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. I was my fault. Now I change in `return` redirect to `view()` it works correctly..

```
public function create()
{
    return view('books.create');
}
```